# Python's equivalence of using namespace

Tags: python, import, namespaces

I have the following Helper.py python script

```
class Helper:
# Helper has many many classes! (AA, BB, CC, DD, ....) not just 2!
    class AA:
        CMD_AA = '8'
        CMD_AB = '1'

    class BB:
        CMD_BA = '0'
        CMD_BB = '1'
```

I created this helper file to make code more readable. So one can write this;

```
# this usage is more readable and makes sense
cmd.a = AA.CMD_AB 
cmd.b = BB.CMD_BB 

# instead of some thing like this where no one knows
# what 1 is interms of a or b!!
cmd.a = 1
cmd.b = 1
```

The helper script is imported in many python files! And the only way i know how to use it is as such

```
from Helper import *
cmd.a = Helper.AA.CMD_AA  # instead of cmd.a = 8
cmd.b = Helper.BB.CMD_BB  # instead of cmd.b = 1
```

Is there a way to get rid of the 'Helper.' I'm already adding more typing. So it'll look like;

```
from Helper import *

#in C++ u can use something like using namespace Helper;
cmd.a = AA.CMD_AA  # instead of cmd.a = 8
cmd.b = BB.CMD_BB  # instead of cmd.b = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should just delete the wrapper Helper class and dedent the rest of the file ... the file itself provides the namespace if you want it

Helper.py

```
class CMD_AA:
    ...
```

main.py

```
import Helper
Helper.CMD_AA
# or just
from Helper import CMD_AA
```

Comment: Indeed, with this suggested change, the equivalent to `using namespace Helper` would be `from Helper import *`. (You tried that before, Sayo, but you had *two* things named Helper: the module file and the class inside that file.) Importing `*` is discouraged in Python just as much as `using namespace` is in C++.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help here. @RobKennedy, i definitely tried the **from Helper import * ** (as shown above in the question), But didn't know that I didn't need the outer class name as indicated by Joran which added the extra complexity.